# Should I bother with Vora 1.2 patching

Tags: vora

I've got Vora 1.2 (not Prod installation, rather educational and presales one) which I installed back in June or July -- almost immediately after its release. I see there is patch for Vora 1.2 in SWDC, released in September, and I know of 1.3 beta-testing which is supposedly ongoing.

Now the question - does it make sense to spend time and apply the patch, or should I just wait for 1.3 GA release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to wait for the Vora 1.3 release. The Vora 1.2 patch has only very few minor fixes.